# Why do toString() and this.toString() produce different results in Chrome's console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Now this has no practical implications at all, but I am curious about this little quirk I stumbled upon.

Basically, in Chrome's developer console, this

```
toString()
```

returns `[object Object]`, whereas this

```
this.toString()
```

returns `[object DOMWindow]`.

As far as I know, this only happens from the console, as can be seen [on this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qft37/). Someone on ##javascript found [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20130518061337/http://thingsilearned.posterous.com/javascript-mystery-of-tostring-global-functio) explaining where the function comes from. However, it doesn't explain the discrepancy there is in the behavior when used within or outside the console.

So why do `toString()` and `this.toString()` produce different results in Chrome's console?

Comment: `"[object Window]"` is returned for both in Firebug.

Comment: Both are `"[object DOMWindow]"` in Chrome 16.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko ah, so maybe there was a bug somewhere that was fixed. If you can find some report of it and post as an answer I'd accept it.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: I'm using Chrome 16 and I get `[object Object]` and `[object DOMWindow]`

Comment: @qwertymk, heres a screenshot using Chrome 16 http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/811/printscreenqw.png/

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko. You are using the watch expressions, not the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebKit happened to use wrong context for global calls in the console.

(Chrome 14):

```
> this
DOMWindow
> this.toString()
"[object DOMWindow]"
> toString()
"[object Object]"
> valueOf()
CommandLineAPI
```

I think this has been fixed over [here](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/77924)

Comment: That would make a lot of sense. `valueOf().toString()` returns "[object Object]".

Comment: When I do `valueOf()` in the console, I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object.

Answer (score 3):

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/anuvus/2/edit) shows that most are `"[object Window]"` this bug mostly applies to console. Note that `Object.prototype.toString.call(window)` still returns global

```
var s = toString;

console.log(s()); // "[object global]"
console.log(toString()); // "[object Object]"
console.log(window.toString()); // "[object Window]"

(function () { 
  var s = toString; 
  console.log(s()); // "[object Undefined]"
})();

(function () { 
  var s = window.toString; 
  console.log(s());  // "[object Window]"
})();

console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(window)); // "[object global]"

console.log(window.toString.call(window)); // "[object DOMWindow]"
```

You found a bag of undefined behaviour. I recommend you run away.

Part of this can be explained away by saying that the global context and the window object are probably not one and the same thing (big hint is [object global]).

Note that `this === window` in all 5 cases.

Note that `window.toString === Object.prototype.toString; // false` explains quite a lot of this. It seems like `window.toString` is a special (but different) function

Comment: Although this is hardly an answer, I agree with your assessment.

Answer (score 1):

1. With the first one, the console tells you about the object `Object`, by which the function toString() is owned and from which everything *inherits*:

   [image: toString()]
2. With the second, it executes the `.toString()` function of `this` which is in this case the window object:

   [image: this.toString()]

---

Before I get a -20 for this answer, it is a deduction (so I'm not sure) based on the output `[object Object]`: for me it tells that the method is executed from `Object`.

If you do the same in Firebug, it actually executes from the `window` object:

[image]

I guess this specific to a console's implementation... or a bug in that Chrome's version.

Comment: But I'm calling the function. It's actually *returning* a string that contains "[object Object]". It's not the console's doing.

Comment: It doesn't tell you something about the function

Comment: @DidierGhys it still doesn't make sense. There shouldn't be any incidence in calling it with or without `this`. The behavior is also different when run from outside the console.

Comment: It is a deduction based on the output `[object Object]`. If you execute `toString()` in Firebug, you get `[object window]`