# Why isn't `toString` equivalent to `window.toString`?

Tags: javascript, console, global-variables, firebug

I'd believed that all global variables were accessible from the global object. So if I can access `x` (and `x` isn't bound locally), then `window.x` is the same value.

However, in a webpage ([on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HtFZB/4/)):

```
window === this // true in Chrome and Firefox
toString === window.toString // true in Chrome and Firefox
```

But in the console:

```
window === this // true in Chrome console and Firebug, false in Firefox web console
toString === window.toString // false in Chrome, Firebug and Firefox web console
```

Why is this? Why is `window` the global object in Chrome's console but `toString` not bound to `window.toString`? What is `toString` bound to in Firefox's console? What other global values are different in the console?

Comment: I [cannot reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/ygtSk/).  What am I missing?

Comment: See comments on my response below, apparently you're seeing a Firebug issue.

Comment: @Travis I've changed the example to avoid confusion with the Firebug issue.

Comment: Try `toString === console.toString` while in the console.

Answer (score 3):

`toString` is not a global variable. It's a method shared by almost all objects, including the `window` object.

An actual global variable would *always* be available on the `window` object.

Comment: I.e., the global object (window) has not actually a property "toString", its prototype has. `window.hasOwnProperty('toString') === false`

Comment: I think author refers to the fact that you can do in console `window.toString === toString` and get `false`.

Comment: OK, so it's not a global variable, but it is available in the global namespace. What else is available in the global namespace but is not an attribute of `window`? What defines what gets into the global namespace?

Comment: @WilfredHughes, I think you misunderstood.  Everything globally will be on window, but not everything available *through* window will be available globally.

Comment: But then why is `toString()` available from the global context at all? And what is it, if it's not `window.toString()`?

Answer (score 2):

perhaps this is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944233/why-do-tostring-and-this-tostring-produce-different-results-in-chromes-cons)?
It's all related to the context, I believe

```
toString.call("foo") == this.toString.call("foo")
```

but

```
tostring.call("foot") != window.toString.call("foo") when this != window
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your claim in Firefox.  They're both returning `[xpconnect wrapped native prototype]`.

To help clear this up:  everything available globally IS available via the global object.  However, there could be properties available through the global object that are not necessarily available globally.  This is due to the prototypal inheritance pattern in Javascript and the lack of specification on how this situation should be handled.

So, should an interpreter attempt to resolve global lookups via prototypal inheritance down the global object chain?  Does the global object inherit from anything else?  I think the various Javascript interpreters are inconsistent here, but someone more familiar with ECMAScript specifications could weigh in.

Comment: I can reproduce this in FF 17.0.1. Perhaps you have an older version?

Comment: Indeed, I was on 15.  Shows how often I use Firefox nowadays.  However, even after updating, I still see the same result.  I'm using [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygtSk/).

Comment: That's *very* interesting, because when I go directly to the firebug console, it gives me the results described by the OP. Why would jsfiddle and the firebug console yield different results?

Comment: That is interesting.  Perhaps it is executing the code from the console in a scope which provides a `toString` function.  Sorry I'm not a Firebug guy so I don't really know.